# Replace part of a string using Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a script wrapped in a string like so:

```
<script async defer>
          {
            "height": "800",
            "c": "d",
            "e": "f",
            "g": "h"
            ...
          }
 </script>
```

I am looking for a way of altering the properties of the inner object.

context:

The script is passed to a React component. If a scale prop is passed, the component should find the height property inside the object, calculate the scale, and replace it with the new scaled height.

e.g

```
<Component 
  script="<script>
          {
            "height": "800",
            "c": "d",
            "e": "f",
            "g": "h"
            ...
          }
  scale=.5
  </script>
```

Should alter the string to be:

```
<script>
          {
            "height": "400",
            "c": "d",
            "e": "f",
            "g": "h"
            ...
          }
</script>
```

Comment: Sure, i've added some context

Comment: No idea, but thanks mate!

Comment: @x15 Is open you can answer it

Comment: What is `scale=.5` doing in there, and why is it not there later?

Comment: Hello, did you read my comment?

Comment: @trincot yes you're right it should be

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your string has an opening and closing script tag and ... JSON.

So it seems best that you extract the JSON part, parse it, manipulate it, and (if really necessary) put the result back in the script wrapper.

Here is some code you could use:

```js
function updateProp(str, key, value) {
    let [, before, json, after] = str.match(/^([^{[]*)([^]*[}\]])([^]*)$/);
    let obj = JSON.parse(json);
    obj[key] = value;
    return before + JSON.stringify(obj) + after;
}

// Example use:
let str = `<script async defer>
    {
        "height": "800",
        "c": "d",
        "e": "f",
        "g": "h"
    }
    scale=.5
 <\/script>`;
 
str = updateProp(str, "height", "400");
console.log(str);
```

Note that the white space in the string will change. I assume this is not an issue, as it does not affect the *meaning/value* of the encoded data.

### A proxy object

You could create a proxy so that you can interact with the string as if it is an object, get/set its properties, and get the string version again (with its `<script>` tag and other things).

Here is how that looks:

```js
function StringAsObject(str) {
    [, this.before, json, this.after] = str.match(/^([^{[]*)([^]*[}\]])([^]*)$/);
    this.obj = JSON.parse(json);
    this.toString = () => this.before + JSON.stringify(this.obj) + this.after;

    return new Proxy(this, {
        get(that, prop) {
            return prop in that ? that[prop] : that.obj[prop];
        },
        set(that, prop, value) {
            return that.obj[prop] = value;
        }
    });
}

// Example use:
let str = `<script async defer>
    {
        "height": "800",
        "c": "d",
        "e": "f",
        "g": "h"
    }
    scale=.5
 <\/script>`;

// Example use
let obj = StringAsObject(str);
 
// act on it as an object
console.log(obj.height); // "800"
obj.height = "400"; 

console.log(obj.toString()); // get the script version again.
```

This still feels very inefficient though, and it would be better you would work straight on objects, not on such strings.

Comment: Thanks for you help :)

Answer (score -1):

This is a simple solution that gets the script content
then runs a substitute on the height given the scale.
Height and scale must exist for change to take affect.

```js
var str = '<script async defer>' + "\n" +
'   {' + "\n" +
'     "height": "800",' + "\n" +
'     "c": "d",' + "\n" +
'     "e": "f",' + "\n" +
'     "g": "h"' + "\n" +
'     ...' + "\n" +
'   }' + "\n" +
'   scale=.5' + "\n" +
'<\/script>' + "\n"
;
// console.log( "From:\n" + str );

var fix = str.replace( 
 /(<script(?:\s+(?=((?:"[\S\s]*?"|'[\S\s]*?'|(?:(?!\/>)[^>])?)+))\2)?\s*>)([\S\s]*?)(<\/script\s*>)/g, 
 function(m,a,b,c,d)
 {
  var content = c;
  if ( content.length == 0 )
          return m;

  content = content.replace( 
   /{[\S\s]*?("\s*height\s*"\s*:\s*"\s*)(\d+)(\s*"[\S\s]*?}[\S\s]*?)[^\S\r\n]*scale\s*=\s*(\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)(?:\r?\n)?/,
   function(M,A,B,C,D)
       {
                            var tdd = B * parseFloat(D);
       return A + tdd + C;
       });
  return a + content + d;
 });

//console.log( "To:\n" + fix );
console.log( fix );
```